# Sort list into sub-lists based on pattern matching R

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

I have a number of TIFF files (each belonging to an image date) in one folder and want to make lists for as many unique dates as there are and then populate those lists with the appropriate files. Ideally, I'd like to have a function where a user would just make changes to the list of dates, though I haven't been able to run a function that would loop through my list of dates. Instead, I've tried to make a function and would run it for each unique date.

```
dates <- list('20180420', '20180522', '20180623', '20180725', '20180810')

# Make a list of all files in the data directory
allFilesDataDirectory <- list.files(path = dataDirectory, pattern = 'TIF$')
# allFilesDataDirectory is a list of 60 TIFF files with the same naming convention along the lines of LC08_L1TP_038037_20180810_20180815_01_T1_B9

allDateLists <- NULL
for (d in dates){
  fileFolderDate <- NULL
  dynamicDateNames <- paste0('fileListL8', d)
  assign(dynamicDateNames, fileFolderDate) 
  allDateLists <- c(allDateLists, dynamicDateNames)
}

myFunction <- function(date, fileNameList){
# files first
  for (i in allFilesDataDirectory){
    # Create a list out of the file name by splitting up the name wherever there is a _ in the name
    splitFileName <- unlist(strsplit(i, "[_]"))
    if(grepl(splitFileName[4], date) & (grepl('B', splitFileName[8]))){
      fileNameList <- c(fileNameList, i)
      print(i)
    } 
    else {
      print('no')
    }
  }
}

myFunction(date = '20180623', fileNameList = 'fileListL820180623')
```

The function runs, but fileListL820180623 is NULL.

When hard coding this, everything works and am not sure of the difference. I tried using assign() (not shown here), but it did nothing.

```
for (i in allFilesDataDirectory){
  # Create a list out of the file name by splitting up the name wherever there is a _ in the name
  splitFileName <- unlist(strsplit(i, "[_]"))
  if(grepl(splitFileName[4], '20180623') & (grepl('B', splitFileName[8]))){
    fileListL820180623 <<- c(fileListL820180623, i)
  } 
  else {
    print('no')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason grepl wasn't working well in this case, but glob2rx worked great.

```
dates <- list('20180420', '20180522', '20180623', '20180725', '20180810')

for (d in dates){
  listLandsatFiles <- list.files(path = dataDirectory, pattern = glob2rx(paste0('*', d, '*B*TIF')))
files
  dynamicFileListName <- paste0('fileListL8', d)
  assign(dynamicFileListName, listLandsatFiles)
}
```

p.s. This might be helpful if you have multiple Landsat images saved in one directory and want to make lists by image date of only the TIFF files ( and perhaps want to make a raster brick later on).

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but it seems you are making it too difficult and you are using poor choices with shortcuts `<<-` and `assign` (there are very few cases where their use is warranted).

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
getTiffPattern <- function(pattern='', folder='.') {
    ff <- list.files(folder, pattern = pattern, full=TRUE)
    grep('\\.tif$', ff, ignore.case = TRUE, value=TRUE)
}

getTiffPattern('20180420')
```

Or for a vector of dates

```
dates <- list('20180420', '20180522', '20180623', '20180725', '20180810')  
x <- lapply(dates, getTiffPattern)
```